# Runtime error for sqlite v2.0 in dotNet 4.0 ? Is this the error?

Tags: c#

I just keep getting this error

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

when I am trying to load the file with a given path.

For example, I would like to load a file named "somename.db" which is an sqlite database filename. I am using System.Data.SQLite,

> ADO.NET 2.0 Data Provider for SQLite
>   Runtime version = v2.0.50727 
>   and i run into that error.

I am using dotNet 4.0 C# Express Edition, ...Thank you.

[**UPDATE**]

Resolve http://www.csharpcity.com/sqlite-ado-net-c-4-0/

To fix, following node to your app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: If this is resolved then please post your own answer with full details how you solved it, not just single link to external website.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, following node to your app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```